# Add an item and price to opportunity line item

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

[image][image]I am trying to get a page to add a item and price to opportunity line item.  I have customized the product page and there is no need for a pricebook as it changes with each product. I created a button to take them straight to the product page from opportunities page then after add the product it then says to save or to save and add price. Once they add price instead of the product going to the line up on the product list I would like it to simply add it to the opportunity line item price included.How do I go about this and I am a newbie so please be gentle. I do know some code but not much and really need to get this done.

Comment: Hi Toni, cold you please add some relevant screenshots to understand what you are trying to do. Hope it will help others to answer the question quickly.

Comment: yes I would love to however I do not see where it will let me do this

Comment: So here is the button on the opportunity page and then the other is the custom product page. I customized the page already there not in VF

Comment: You would have mention that this is a Flow.

Comment: I have it in a flow as well

Comment: if your button is associated with apex controller, please use [edit] to post that code; if it launches a flow, please use [edit] to expose screen shot(s) of your flow.  Ultimately, you have to create `OpportunityLineItem` with `OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntryId=somePBEIdThatYouQueriedFor`